# Passing javascript variables to webpack from htm page

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

Lets say I have a index.htm file which includes my webpack bundle.js.
But before the bundle.js is added I have a variable setup...

```
  myVar = 'test';
```

Now if I reference this var in my entry.js which is included in the bundle.js... it says it is undefined... How do I get a variable from my htm page into webpack?

Answer (score 0):

As you defined it, `myVar` is global.

You could use `window.myVar` in entry.js without a problem.

Comment: Thanks very much... I have it working now.. I was being a fool... I was defining variables after the document was loaded and of course these where not available in the bundle.js since this is part of the initial page load. Sorry for the inconvenience.. Your answer prompted me to figure it out..